# Set column value to another column in the same row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table foo:

```
Id col1 col2  result
-- ---- ---- -----
1   a     b 
2   c     d
```

I need to update row with id 1 like this:

```
update foo set result = 'str1=x,str2=col2_value' where Id = 2
```

result after update must be:

```
Id col1 col2  result
-- ---- ---- ----------
1   a     b   str1=x,str2=b
2   c     d
```

How to put value of col2 to the string in result?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Please, don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: You say you need to update the row with id = 1, then you do `where id=2`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: oh it is oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
update foo set result=CONCAT('str1=x,str2=',col2) where Id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the concat function:

[MySQL Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE foo SET result = CONCAT('str1=x,str2=',col2) WHERE id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE foo SET result = 'str1=x,str2 ='+col2+'' FROM foo WHERE id = 1;